# Mantra scriptures

Tags: scripture, mantras, tantra

Which scripture contains list of various mantras to achieve various things in life? It should contain actual mantras not general guidelines about chanting mantras.

Comment: Atharva veda is the source

Comment: following any random mantra from any random book will yield little to no result whatsoever....

Answer (score 3):

*Tāntrika nibandha* is the category of texts you are looking for.

You can consult the following texts that are available online for free

1. *Prapañcasāra Tantra* of *Adi Shaṅkara* with *Vivaraṇa* commentary by his disciple *Padmapāda*
2. *Śāradātilaka Tantra* of *Lakṣmaṇa Desikendra* with *Padārthādarśa* commentary by the polymath *Rāghava Bhatta* of *Vārānasī*
3. *Mantramahodahi* by *Mahīdhara Bhatta* of *Vārānasī* (author of the  *Vedadīpa* commentary on the *Mādhyandina* recession of the *Vājasaneyī Saṁhitā* of *Śuklayajurveda*) alongside his own *Naukā* commentary.
4. *Gautamiya Tantra* (for *mantra*s related to *Kṛṣṇa*)
5. *Nāradapañcarātra - Jñānāmṛtasāra*
6. *Rāmārcanacandrikā* of *Ānanda Vana* (for *mantra*s related to *Rāma*)
7. *Vṛhattantrasāra* by *Kṛṣṇānanda Āgamavāgiśa* of *Navadvīpa*
8. *Āgamatattvavilāsa* by *Raghunātha Tarkavāgiśa* of *Napāṛa*(?) in eastern Bengal
9. *Prāṇatoṣaṇī Tantra* of *Rāmatoṣaṇa Vidyālaṅkāra* at the behest of *Prāṇakṛṣṇa Viśvāsa* of *Khaṛadaha*
10. *Śrīvidyarṇava Tantra* of *Vidyāranya* (not to be confused with the pontiff of *Sṛṅgerī maṭha* who was also the *guru* of *Harihara* & *Bukkārāya*. This *Vidyāranya* was an older contemporary of *Rāmānuja* & served a feudal lord of probably *Rājamahedravaram*)
11. *Iśānaśivagurudevapaddhati* of *Iśānaśiva* of *Kerala* (for *Shaiva mantra*s)
12. *Ākāśabhairavakalpa*
13. *Prapañcasārasaṁgraha* of *Gīrvānendra Sarasvatī*
14. Chapters 63 - 91 of *Nārada Purāṇa*'s *pūrvārdha* (N.B it has some inaccuracies).
15. *Sanatkumārasaṁhitā* - a *Pañcarātra* text
16. *Tantrasārasaṁgraha* of *Madhva* with *Padyamālā* exposition by *Jayatirtha*
17. *Puraścaryārnava* of unnamed *paṇḍita*s at the behest of *Mahārāja Pratāpasiṁha Śāh* of *Nepāla*
18. *Mantramahārṇava* of *Mādhava Rāya Vaidya* from *Visāhunagara*(?) of *Rājasthana* (for occult rites & black magic)

However, in order to utilise the *mantra*s given in these texts, you must atleast receive *mantradikṣā* from a bona-fide *guru* who has a clear *gurupaṅkti* (i.e the *guru* must have received the *mantra* in question through an unbroken lineage consisting of his/her own *guru*, *parama-guru* i.e *guru*'s *guru*, *parāpara-guru* i.e *guru* of *parama-guru* & *parameṣṭhī-guru* i.e *guru* of *parāpara-guru*, all of whom belong to a legitimate *sampradāya*) & be authorised to perform *puraścaraṇa* of the same.

*Puraścaraṇa* is a *Tāntrika* rite which involves the votary perform *japa* of the *mantra* a certain lakh number of times from sunrise to midday, following by *homa* of the same 1/10 times, *tarpaṇa* 1/100 times, *abhiṣeka* 1/1000 times & feeding *brāhmaṇa*s numbering 1/10000th of the original number. (That is to say that if a *Tāntrika mantra* requires to be recited 1 lakh times & on the first day, the votary is able to perform *japa* of the same 20,000 times, then he must perform *homa* of the same *mantra* 2,000 times, *tarpaṇa* 200 times, *abhiṣeka* 20 times & feed 2 *brahmaṇa*s on that day & repeat the same procedure continuously for the next 4 days) in order to achieve *mantra-siddhi*. It has some very strict rules like living off upon alms & ban on holding conversation in any language other than Sanskrit with anybody other than the *brāhmaṇa*s employed in the rite, alongside the other usual restraints on behavior & diet. Although it requires a considerable amount of time, money & resource, *puraścaraṇa* is a far better alternative to the varieties of austerities performed by *muni*s of the past as described in other texts (like standing on a single toe while completely avoiding food, sleep & sex for many years at a row with exposing the body to elements) to obtain boons.

As somebody has already pointed out, the *Atharvaveda* is also filled with *mantra*s aimed at attaining various material & spiritual benefits but mere chanting of the same will not yield fruit. It requires performance of *homa* according the rules laid down in the *kalpa-sūtra*s of *Ātharvaṇa*s of that *mantra* in order to for it to be effective. Currently, the practice of *Atharvaveda* is restricted to a section of *Nāgara brahmaṇa*s in Gujarat (*Śaunakīya śākhā*) & a section of *Utkala brahmaṇa*s in Odisha (*Paippalāda śākhā*). In the *Skandapurāṇa*, it is said that *Bhagavāna Śiva* had performed an *Ātharvaṇa homa* of the *Ātharvaṇa mantra*s aimed to repel & destroy enemy forces in which He offered His own blood into the fire, resulting in creation of a *kṛtyā* who laid waste to the *Asura* armies of *Andhaka*. [N.B -  *Kṛtyā* can also be invoked in a *Tāntrika* manner for both beneficent & maleficent purposes & can be repelled by invoking *Pratyaṅgirā*, alongside the application of *kṛtyā*-repellent *Ātharvaṇa mantra*s.]

So it is clear that *mantra-śāstra* is no child's play. It due to lack of awareness about its intricacies that common people get exploited by charlatans professing to be *mantra-siddha*s, resulting in the word *tantra* becoming synonymous with orgies, superstitions & black magic for a lay person.

Comment: Is there a way I could contact you privately?